# Save My Camera! (FPC Breakout?)

Tags: fpc

I recently took apart my camera to solder some wires onto the take video button so I could trigger taking videos remotely. The button for this was housed inside a plastic housing and all I could find was a thin fpc connector that contained lines for several buttons. I scraped off the plastic with a knife and attempted soldering on a very small wire. BIG MISTAKE.

The iron melted the plastic, but not the solder paste! It also managed to rip/melt the wires at that point in the connector.

[image: FPC Connector Damage]

I have two questions for the EE Community:

(1) How can I fix the connector I destroyed

(2) How can I attach wires to this connector for an oscilloscope reading and eventual automation?

One Idea I had was to use conductive paste...

Comment: @DaveTweed What more understanding do you expect to see in this question?

Comment: what make and model is the camera?

Answer (score 1):

wires 1-2 and 5 look to be broken, so they will have to be repaired, if its just button contacts you can likely get away with conductive expoxy laid down in very thin lines, wont be easy, but should be possible

as for how you would connect your wires, I would recommend attacking the switch, as it will have bigger pins that are soldered to the flex pcb, you may also find your camera already has some interface on it to act as a trigger, change modes, etc, you would just need to determine what it is for your particular brand.